# Can anyone explain me magic methods and operator overloading in simple words?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, magic-methods

I cant understand the `__add__ / __sub__` methods , why they need them , how they work  and the overloading concept, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It makes your life easy and makes your code more human readable. Please take a look at my simple use case that Ived made for you to understand.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__total = 0

    def buy(self, count):
        self.__total += count

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.total + other.total

    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.__total


toyota = Car()
honda = Car()

toyota.buy(3)
print(toyota.total)  # prints 3

honda.buy(5)
print(honda.total)  # prints 5

car_total = honda + toyota
print(car_total)  # prints 8
```

Comment: Excellent way of explaining (+1)

Comment: While this might be an example, it doesn't actually **explain** anything. While this code snippet may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762). Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.